# My Unity First Person character camera is weird and wobbly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial here:https://youtu.be/Sqb-Ue7wpsI?t=3727
and I am currently programming the First Person camera but unfortunately I have no idea where the bug is hidden and when I press play the FPS camera looks like a drunk person vision instead of smooth movements and the Mouse X and Mouse Y might be the root cause of it but here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CMovements : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform Playr, Lookr;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool Invertaxis;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool Unlockes = true;
    [SerializeField]
    private float Sensitivities = 8f;
    [SerializeField]
    private int smeufsteps = 10;
    [SerializeField]
    private float Smooth_weit = 0.4f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float rollangles = 0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector2 defaulteslookleameats = new Vector2(-70f, 80f);
    private Vector2 Lookangles;
    private Vector2 Currentmauspos; 
    private Vector2 Smoothmove;
    private float Currentrollangles;
    private int last_leuk_frames;
    [SerializeField]
    private float Rollspeed = 3f;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Lockunddelockcursor();
        Lookaround();
    }

    void Lockunddelockcursor()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
          if(Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked)
                {
                    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            } 
            else
            {
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
                Cursor.visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void Lookaround()
    {
        Currentmauspos = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis(Mausexis.MausY),Input.GetAxis(Mausexis.MausX));
        Lookangles.x += Currentmauspos.x * Sensitivities * (Invertaxis ? 1f : -1f);
        Lookangles.y += Currentmauspos.y * Sensitivities;
        Lookangles.x = Mathf.Clamp(Lookangles.x, defaulteslookleameats.x, defaulteslookleameats.y);
        Lookr.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Lookangles.x,0f,0f); 
        Playr.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, Lookangles.y, 0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the camera attached to a game object, or is it just free floating? Camera's directly attached to a game object can get jerky if the parent object's movement is also jerky.

Comment: Yes, I have attached it to the parent object of the player.